# Firebase sign in not working after I sign out

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication, swift3

So the first sign in into the Swift UI app works fine. I sign in and the view changes to the home view from the sign in view. However, after I log out, the sign in doesn't cause my view to change, so I assume it doesn't work.

Here is my AuthViewModel where I handle the sign in and sign out.

```
import FirebaseAuth

class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = AuthViewModel()

    private(set) var authSubscription: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    @Published var currentUser: User?
    @Published var error: Error?

    init() {
        authSubscription = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [weak self] (auth, user) in
            self?.currentUser = user
        }
    }

    func signIn(email: String, password: String) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                self?.error = error
            } else {
                self?.error = nil
            }
        }
    }

    func signUp(email: String, password: String) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                self?.error = error
            } else {
                self?.error = nil
            }
        }
    }

    func signOut() {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
        } catch let error {
            self.error = error
        }
    }
}
```

Also here is how I am switching from my sign up view to the home view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var screenOn = 0
    @EnvironmentObject var authViewModel: AuthViewModel

    var body: some View {
        if let user = authViewModel.currentUser {
            if screenOn == 0 {
                someView(screenOn: $screenOn)
                    .onAppear(perform: UIApplication.shared.addTapGestureRecognizer)
                    .onOpenURL { url in
                        let link = url.absoluteString

                      
                    }
            } else if screenOn == 1 {
                someView(screenOn: $screenOn)
                    .onAppear {
                        authViewModel.signOut()
                    }
            } else if screenOn == 3 {
                someView(screenOn: $screenOn)
            } else if screenOn == 4 {
                someView(screenOn: $screenOn)
            }
        } else {
            Loginpage()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could try setting `currentUser = nil`, in your `func signOut()`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I added that code, but the same thing happens.

Comment: The code is incomplete. If there's no current user, the app goes to `LoginPage` but we don't know what that is. Likewise if the code in `AuthViewModel` class runs, there's no indication of any functions being called, and even if they were, no further action occurs whether a user authenticates or not, other than a var is set or nil'd and then that class going out of scope. Can you clarify what's being asked?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a12738750%20listener&searchOn=3

Answer (score 1):

```
The **ScreenOn** variable is not updated correctly after calling the signOut fun.

func signOut() 
{
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
             self.screenOn = 0  // Add this line 
        } catch let error {
            self.error = error
        }
    }

Add a breakpoint to verify that the correct view is being loaded.
```